# Can we use PostgreSQL with PolyBase To connect Hadoop?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

Microsoft finally enters into the bigdata world and come up with PolyBase interface to connect with Hadoop so existing MS SQL server users can take advantage of Hadoop ecosystem to store large amount of data.

Here I have 1 question can we use postgreSQL instead of MS SQL Server to connect with Hadoop using PolyBase interface which was recently released with MS SQL server 2016.

I knew there are many other ways to do that but wants to know specially using PolyBase (PDW).

Actually my company always welcome solution where microsoft involved as majority of application based on their platform.

I knew it will be possible using PolyBase Parallel Data Warehouse but needs some hints to do the same.

Thank you so much, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, PolyBase is a feature within Microsoft SQL Server products only (SQL DW, APS/PDW, SQL Server 2016 and later).